# What would be the best to clean up an output file with bash?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I was wondering if anyone could tell me a good way to clean this txt file with awk, grep, cut etc..? And the most elegant way. Ive managed to get rid of quite a lot of garbage (the file is much bigger than this) but Im having no joy getting rid of the "/" and adding them to a new separate line.

This is my attemped line of code

```
cat nmap_results |grep [A-Za-z0-9] |sort -u > New_results.txt
```

and here is the results:

```
Host: 192.168.15.201 () Ports: 21/closed/tcp//ftp///, 22/closed/tcp//ssh///, 23/closed/tcp//telnet///, 25/closed/tcp//smtp///, 80/closed/tcp//http///, 110/closed/tcp//pop3///, 139/open/tcp//netbios-ssn///, 443/closed/tcp//https///, 445/open/tcp//microsoft-ds///, 3389/closed/tcp//ms-wbt-server///
Host: 192.168.15.201 () Status: Up
Host: 192.168.15.202 () Ports: 21/closed/tcp//ftp///, 22/filtered/tcp//ssh///, 23/closed/tcp//telnet///, 25/filtered/tcp//smtp///, 80/open/tcp//http///, 110/closed/tcp//pop3///, 139/closed/tcp//netbios-ssn///, 443/filtered/tcp//https///, 445/filtered/tcp//microsoft-ds///, 3389/closed/tcp//ms-wbt-server///
Host: 192.168.15.202 () Status: Up
Host: 192.168.15.205 () Ports: 21/open/tcp//ftp///, 22/closed/tcp//ssh///, 23/closed/tcp//telnet///, 25/closed/tcp//smtp///, 80/open/tcp//http///, 110/closed/tcp//pop3///, 139/open/tcp//netbios-ssn///, 443/open/tcp//https///, 445/open/tcp//microsoft-ds///, 3389/open/tcp//ms-wbt-server///
Host: 192.168.15.205 () Status: Up
```

Thanks Wez

Comment: 1. Show your attempt. 2. Show your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace commas for a linefeed and replace forwardslashes with a space.
The result is a lot more readable;

```
$ sed 's/,/\n/g' logfile.txt | sed 's/\// /g'
Host: 192.168.15.201 () Ports: 21 closed tcp  ftp
 22 closed tcp  ssh
 23 closed tcp  telnet
 25 closed tcp  smtp
 80 closed tcp  http
 110 closed tcp  pop3
 139 open tcp  netbios-ssn
 443 closed tcp  https
 445 open tcp  microsoft-ds
 3389 closed tcp  ms-wbt-server    Host: 192.168.15.201 () Status: Up Host: 192.168.15.202 () Ports: 21 closed tcp  ftp
 22 filtered tcp  ssh
 23 closed tcp  telnet
 25 filtered tcp  smtp
 80 open tcp  http
 110 closed tcp  pop3
 139 closed tcp  netbios-ssn
 443 filtered tcp  https
 445 filtered tcp  microsoft-ds
 3389 closed tcp  ms-wbt-server    Host: 192.168.15.202 () Status: Up Host: 192.168.15.205 () Ports: 21 open tcp  ftp
 22 closed tcp  ssh
 23 closed tcp  telnet
 25 closed tcp  smtp
 80 open tcp  http
 110 closed tcp  pop3
 139 open tcp  netbios-ssn
 443 open tcp  https
 445 open tcp  microsoft-ds
 3389 open tcp  ms-wbt-server    Host: 192.168.15.205 () Status: Up
```